# Simple confusion with DATALENGTH()

Tags: sql-server-2008

`DATALENGTH()` function returns the length of the data in BYTES.

The table is like this:

```
create table tb3 
( 
id int, 
id2 varchar(100), 
nome varchar(200)
)

| id      | id2   | nome  |   |
|---------|-------|-------|---|
| 1       | 1     | r     |   |
| 1       | 11    | r1    |   |
| 1       | 111   | r11   |   |
| 1       | 1111  | r111  |   |
| 1       | 11111 | r1111 |   |
| 11      | 11111 | r1111 |   |
| 1111111 | 11111 | r1111 |   |
```

but when i run it like this:

`select DATALENGTH(id), DATALENGTH(id2), DATALENGTH(nome) from tb3`

```
| (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) |   |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|---|
| 4                | 1                | 1                |   |
| 4                | 2                | 2                |   |
| 4                | 3                | 3                |   |
| 4                | 4                | 4                |   |
| 4                | 5                | 5                |   |
| 4                | 5                | 5                |   |
| 4                | 5                | 5                |
```

Why it says each varchar character is using only 1 byte?
If i'm not mistaken, a varchar uses 2 bytes + number of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'DATALENGTH()' function returns the length of just the *data*, those extra two bytes are considered "meta-data" - information about the data and/or its storage.

You get the same value if you pass the function a string literal (`DATALENGTH('12345')` returns 5) - this wouldn't be the case if the function accounted for storage overheads as well as the string's content.

To account for storage overhead the `DATALENGTH` function would need to know or be able to derive where a value has come from, and the structure of that location, if the data is compressed, etc., and accounting for all that would make the function far less efficient.

Comment: So in reality, those bytes should be for example n+2? if I had understood right, the data is consuming for example 3bytes (n+2) in the storage, but SQL Server only says it's N with the function DATALENGTH().

Comment: @RacerSQL - yes, it is returning the length of the data, not the amount if information taken by a column containing it. It will return the same length if instead you pass it a variable (`DATALENGTH(@LuggageCode)`) or even a literal value (`DATALENGTH('12345')`) and in neither of those cases does the meta-data involved in table storage come into effect.

Answer (score -1):

kindly refer below articles to understand the concept of row storage and extra byte overhead :

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-null-bitmap-size/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608000/char-and-varchar-datatype-storage-at-page-level-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment94077524_53608000